# IIS, application pool stop Automatically

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, application-pool

I am running WCF services on IIS 7.5 with .NET framework version 4.5 and it is in integrated mode. Whenever I deploy new code on IIS, it causes application pool to crash resulting in 503 error. I tried to dig into code but I am not able to figure out the root cause of the problem because of the large code base. I have ensured that it is not because of any server or IIS setting (as reverting the build makes IIS normal). I have also looked into event logs but not able to find anything, I am already logging application error but nothing is helping. Is there anyway I can trap the event or error just before crashing pool as I am running it integrated mode? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Enable WCF tracing to see more, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing Unhandled exceptions should be recorded and you will see what they are.

Comment: Tracing did not work in my case. While doing some debugging and comparing the previous code, I was able to identify the problem. It was throwing stackoverflow exception. I am not sure if we can find this issue in tracing.